# How can I link images that are already on the server to a new product uploaded via api with only one call?

Tags: magento2.3.1, image-upload

I uploaded about `12000 products` to `pub/media/<custom-dir-name>`

I now want to link them to products as I upload them using the `API`.

The product creates just fine, but no images are linked.

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "sku",
    "name": "name",
    "price": 9.99,
    "attribute_set_id": 9,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "weight": "0.5",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 2,
                "category_id": "5"
            },
            {
                "position": 3,
                "category_id": "4"
            }
        ],
          "stock_item": {
            "qty": "10",
            "is_in_stock": true
        }

    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "description"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "image",
            "value": "/<dir-name>/A41024DGAM.jpg"
        },
         {
          "attribute_code": "small_image",
          "value": "/<dir-name>/A41024DGAM.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
          "value": "/<dir-name>/A41024DGAM.jpg"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the JSON, it seems you have appended the images with the directory path i.e. **`/<dir-name>/A41024DGAM.jpg`**

Are the images moved in the same way to `pub/media/<dir-name>` ?

Can you check if you can see the images in Admin > Catalog > Products > [Edit Product] > Images And Videos ? If Yes, Try to upload a image from Admin and check if it gets uploaded and show up on Admin as well as Frontend, this is to confirm that the images are getting uploaded and show up when uploaded from Admin and there is no permission issue.

I hope you may have already done the `bin/magento indexer:reindex` to do indexing, `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` and `bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a csv to upload the images